# How to parse the particular first child <dateline> tag data of a parent tag <body> using XSL 1.0 and skip the value in the output

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

From the below sample input and respective output, I need a XSL transformation to skip only the fist occurrence of the `<dateline>` field in under `<body>` parent tag.

```
       <!--Given sample Input XML: -->
            <content>
               <data>
                <datatext>
                     <message name="message">
                        <p>Test message paragraph. 
                           <dateline name="dateline">Message datelines</dateline>? 
                           <annotation type="note">Test message Note.</annotation>
                        </p>
                     </message>
                     <head name="head">
                        <p>Test Head paragraph <annotation type="note">Head notes </annotation> paragraph.
                            <dateline name="dateline">Head dateline</dateline>
                        </p>
                     </head>
                     <body name="body">
                        <p>
                           Test first Body paragraph.
                           <annotation type="note">First Body notes.</annotation>
                        </p>
                        <p>Test Second Body paragraph.</p>
                        <p>
                           <annotation type="note">Second Body notes.</annotation>
                           Test third Body paragraph.
                           <dateline name="dateline">SECOND DATELINE</dateline>
                        </p>
                        <p>Test Fouth Body paragraph.</p>
                        <p>
                           <dateline name="dateline">THIRD DATELINE</dateline> 
                           Test fourth Body paragraph.
                           <annotation type="note">Third Body notes.</annotation>
                        </p>
                     </body>
                  </datatext>
               </data>
            </content>
```

The expected output, the first occurrence of the `<dateline>` tag should be removed,

```
        <!-- Expected Output XML -->
        <content>
           <data>
            <datatext>
                 <message name="message">
                    <p>Test message paragraph. 
                       <dateline name="dateline">Message datelines</dateline>? 
                       <annotation type="note">Test message Note.</annotation>
                    </p>
                 </message>
                 <head name="head">
                    <p>Test Head paragraph <annotation type="note">Head notes </annotation> paragraph.
                        <dateline name="dateline">Head dateline</dateline>
                    </p>
                 </head>
                 <body name="body">
                    <p>
                       Test first Body paragraph.
                       <annotation type="note">First Body notes.</annotation>
                    </p>
                    <p>Test Second Body paragraph.</p>
                    <p>
                       <annotation type="note">Second Body notes.</annotation>
                       Test third Body paragraph.
                    </p>
                    <p>Test Fouth Body paragraph.</p>
                    <p>
                       <dateline name="dateline">THIRD DATELINE</dateline> 
                       Test fourth Body paragraph.
                       <annotation type="note">Third Body notes.</annotation>
                    </p>
                 </body>
              </datatext>
           </data>
        </content>
```

Comment: <!-- the input xml is looking like -->

Comment: <!-- the sample output body section xml is looking like -->   <field name="body">
 <p>Test first Body paragraph.
  <span class="note">First Body notes.</span>
 </p>
 <p>Test Second Body paragraph.</p>
 <p>Test third Body paragraph.
  <span class="note">Second Body notes.</span>
 </p>
 <p>
  <span class="dateline">THIRD DATELINE</span> 
  Test fourth Body paragraph.
  <span class="note">Third Body notes.</span>
 </p>
</field>

Answer (score 1):

> skip only the fist occurrence of the `<dateline>` field in under
>   `<body>` parent tag

First, `body` is an **ancestor** of `dateline`, not the **parent**.

Now, since you want to copy everything except one node, it would be best to start with the identity transform template (that copies everything) as the rule, and add an exception for the node in question:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="body//dateline[generate-id()=generate-id(ancestor::body/descendant::dateline[1])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Why must this be so complicated:**

In order to **select** the first `dateline` descendant of `body`, you must use the expression:

```
body/descendant::dateline[1]
```

and not:

```
body//dateline[1]
```

This is explained in the [XPath specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev):

> **NOTE**: The location path `//para[1]` does *not* mean the same as the location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first
>   descendant `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para`
>   elements that are the first `para` children of their parents.

However, the expression:

```
body/descendant::dateline[1]
```

is not a valid **match pattern**. Although patterns may use the // operator, they must not use the descendant axis: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#patterns

Therefore I have chosen to match **any** `dateline` that is a descendant of `body`, and add a *predicate* that compares the unique id of the current `dateline` with the one that is truly the first `descendant` of the ancestor `body`. This works because the descendant axis *is* allowed in a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="bdl" select="//body//dateline"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dateline[index-of($bdl,.) = 1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

At first I thought you could get by with just

```
<xsl:template match="//body//dateline[1]"/>
```

But this doesn't work since the `[1]` predicate is focus and context dependent, and both `dateline` tags in the body are first under their immediate parent.  This solution first builds a sequence of all body `dateline` tags (in `$bdl`) and then deletes only the one that matches the first entry in the list.

There is probably a "better" or more idiomatic way of accomplishing this, and I hope one of the XSLT gurus will answer as well.

Comment: This question is tagged `xslt-1.0`. The `index-of()` function requires XSLT 2.0.